# How to gain access to Ubuntu again?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I recently tried to remove Ubuntu from my PC because I was not able to use it. So I finally found a way, but I still had to copy a few files over and I had already disabled the boot menu.

So how do you reverse, command prompt: `bootrec /fixmbr`, to gain access to Ubuntu again?

Comment: You wrote "still had to copy a few", can please explain better? What did you copy? From where to where? Is your installed system still there? Do you need help to restore grub boot loader?

Comment: I have a few documents that I stiil need to copy before I boot a new OS. So I read on on wikihow to use the  command prompt :bootrec/fixmbr to disable the OS selection because I had both Ubuntu and windows

Comment: Relax. If you don't do anything to remove your documents (like deleting them or formatting that partition), they will stay as they are, even if you boot your computer in Windows. From Windows you won't be able to see them, but they will still be there. Easiest way to recover them is to start your PC using an Ubuntu live-usb system like the one you used to install Ubuntu first time. When prompted, choose the option "Try Ubuntu": from there you will be able to mount your original Ubuntu system partition (and your Windows partitions), and copy your files to an USB disk, for example.

Comment: @gerlos I recommend adding that information to your answer. (Even by itself it might work as an answer to this.)

Comment: @EliahKagan from the question it was unclear to me what the OP wanted to do (restore system boot or recover some files?). Comments helped me understand it better, but still I'm unsure: should I edit the question to make it more explicit and fix my answer to match it, so it can be helpful to other people passing by?

Comment: @gerlos Whether or not the question is edited (by you or anyone), I think it would be appropriate for you to expand your answer. The question already includes, "I still had to copy a few files over and I had already disabled the boot menu" which I think it sufficient to show that information about how to retrieve files from a non-booting Ubuntu installation is within its scope. (I don't recommend removing any of the current content from your answer, though.)

Answer (score 4):

Most of the boot problems can be solved in a semi-automatic way using a tool called [`boot-repair`](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/).

Usually this involves booting the PC from a live-CD or live-USB, enabling an additional repository, install boot-repair and then run it, following the instructions given by the app.

[image]

See here for details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Anyways, **you don't need to restore Ubuntu boot if your goal is just to recover some files and documents stored in Ubuntu partition**. From Windows you won't be able to see them, but they will still be there.

Easiest way to recover those files is to start your PC using an [Ubuntu live-usb](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) system like the one you used to install Ubuntu first time.

When prompted, choose the option *"Try Ubuntu"*: from there you will be able to mount your original Ubuntu system partition (and your Windows partitions, if present), and copy your files to an USB disk, for example, or even to a directory in Windows partition.

Your partitions and disks will appear as disk icons on the left of your screen, just click on them to see their contents.

Usually personal files are stored in sub directories of the `/home/` directory of your Ubuntu partition.